# Hardware issue: computer plays beep sounds at startup, and then turns off

Tags: cpu, boot, fan

Turns out that after moving, my computer got damaged somehow. I installed my computer 2 days ago. I didn't check the state of the hardware parts and turned the pc on recklessly, not realizing that the **cpu fan was dettached** from the cpu. After this I reattached the fan. The computer worked kind of faulty after that, because at the time of startup, it would play a long beep (different from the normal beep) and won't display anything. I tried restarting after this incident and it got fixed (don't know how, but it did), and I was even able to play some videogames for some hours (more than 5).

This morning I tried to get this issue sorted out by checking again the cpu and in general, the connections, and for my surprise, at the time of turning it on again, the computer wouldn't boot at all. I reapplied some thermal paste to the cpu and fan, but got no results (I did this because the old paste was very badly distributted along the surface of both cpu and fan). Now every time I turn it on, the computer acts randomly:

- sometimes at startup, it plays a long continous beep and then turns off.
- one time it played a long continous beep and got to the windows password input screen, but then it turned off
- More frequently, I turn it on and after some seconds, it turns off without any sound.

[You can check this video I recorded, which features how the computer behaves most of the time](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ-eH1fIL3U)

[Another one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bp26vPBk4A)

I tried troubleshoting it myself by disconnecting my graphic card, rams, HDD and even the cpu and its fan with no result.

Computer specs:

Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 processor, Nvidia xfx gtx 260 black edition, 4 GB ram, 500 GB hard drive, Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: It sounds like you did the equivalent of driving your car with a broken fan belt until it stopped running. Don't be surprised that it won't move now. "He's dead, Jim"

Comment: Well, It was only for a couple seconds, because it wouldn't turn on without the fan. :(((

Comment: I just took a close look at the pci express slot where my graphic card and noted that it looks odd (check it here http://i.imgur.com/esLAU.jpg). Withouth the graphic card and only woth the cpu connected, i get the long beep but the computer doesnt turn off. Have any of you guys experienced something like this? Thanks...

Comment: Ouch, that video card slot looks unfixable. Time for a new motherboard at least, possibly the video card is dead as well; does it have cracks or loose parts?

Comment: I checked my card and it indeed looks suspicious: there are some cracks on the back. I guess due to the handling of the pc by the movers damaged the card. Thanks for the feedback guys, I think i'll start saving money.

Comment: Thanks for doing a good job explaining what you had already tried and where you were in the process. Well-asked!

Comment: Looks like you have a secondary PCIE x16 slot there (the orange one in your photo). Have you tried putting your graphics card in there? If that doesn't work (and the GPU itself is damaged), you might ask around for a cheap one to use in the interim. You can get a graphics card that _works_ for probably around $30 USD, it just won't be fancy. Better than nothing.

Comment: Between the warped slot and a possibly-cracked video card, I'd recommend buying a new motherboard and video card. You might be able to get something to limp along by using the secondary slot or a cheapo card, but with the damage on both parts, whatever you manage to rig probably won't be reliable in the long term. Computers that short out or crash when bumped are, in my experience, not fun to use.

Comment: @nhinkle thank you very much, I tried my best to explain myself because english is not my main language.
I tried what you guys suggested -plugging the card in the other slot-, and although it gets after the POST, there's still that annoying long continuous beep, that possibly indicates a short circuit in the PCI area. Fortunately enough, I got my belongings under an insurance, so I will hopefully replace all the damaged components. Thank you very much guys, mean a lot.

Answer (score 1):

These are called [Power-On Self-Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) or POST beeps. Each motherboard has its own codes, but they are typically given if the RAM is bad, or there is no reply from the CPU or video cards. Consult the manual or web site of your motherboard manufacturer.

You could try swapping RAM, CPU, or video cards with a known good one. If these are built in your motherboard it is probably time for a new motherboard. You can probably still save your data by chaining your hard drive to a working machine.

Comment: According to my motherboard manual, said mobo is an AWARD one, and the "Continuous long beep" means graphic card not inserted properly. I'm pretty sure it is well inserted and powered. Unfortunately, I don't have any friends (lol) because I just moved from another country, so I can't troubleshoot with spare parts. Thanks!